# JavaScript prototypes

Tags: javascript, prototype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: Class.method vs. Class.prototype.method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635116/javascript-class-method-vs-class-prototype-method)

What's the difference between creating a prototype like this:

```
Date.foo = function(bar) {
    alert(bar);
};
```

And this:

```
Date.prototype.foo = function(bar) {
    alert(bar);
};
```

Why/when should I use either?

Comment: See: [JavaScript: Class.method vs. Class.prototype.method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635116/javascript-class-method-vs-class-prototype-method)

Comment: Sometimes I take it for granted that the question must have been asked before, and close the question blindly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the first example, foo is a constructor method, its like a 'static' method in java.  The second is like defining a method foo on a class -- it is scoped to the instance.

you would access the first like

```
Date.foo()
```

and the second like

```
Date d = new Date()
d.foo()
```

or in another method on an instance of Date like

```
this.foo()
```