# Javascript "if" Order of Operations

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, operator-precedence

So let's say you have a really basic person object with two values and one function:

```
function personObject() {
    this.name = 'First Name';
    this.placeInLine = 1;
    this.setPlaceInLine = function(place) {
        this.placeInLine = place;
    }
}
```

And we setup some variables like this:

```
var john = new personObject();
var bill = new personObject();
var message = "";
```

Now look at the three codes snippets below...

---Code #1---

```
if(john.placeInLine < bill.placeInLine) message = "John is before Bill";
else message = "John is not before Bill";
```

RESULT: message = "John is not before Bill"; // because 1 is not less than 1

---Code #2---

```
bill.setPlaceInLine(2); // change Bill's place to 2 (instead of default of 1)
if(john.placeInLine < bill.placeInLine) message = "John is before Bill";
else message = "John is not before Bill";
```

RESULT: message = "John is before Bill"; // because 1 less than 2;

---Code #3---

```
if(john.placeInLine < bill.setPlaceInLine(2)) message = "John is before Bill";
else message = "John is not before Bill";
```

RESULT: message = "John is not before Bill": // why?

Is the .setPlaceInLine function being called after the comparison?  Or is the act of running that function returning something that is then being compared to john.placeInLine?

Comment: fixed that in the snippets - sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `setPlaceInLine` method has no explicit return, and therefore returns `undefined`. And `1 < undefined` evaluates to `false`: `undefined` gets converted to `Number`, giving `NaN`, and `1 < NaN` is certainly `false` (`1 > NaN` is `false` too, btw).

While you can fix this by making your setter method return the assigned value:

```
PersonObject.prototype.setPlaceInLine = function(place) {
  return this.placeInLine = place;
}
```

... I think it's better (more clean) to use the setters and getters separately (like in your code #2 example).

As a sidenote, I'd recommend using prototypes to set up object methods (like I did in my example code). The reason for this is pretty well explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1635143/1229023): basically with prototypes you will make just a single Function entity, used by all the created objects, when with `this.someMethod` you would create a new Function each time a constructor is called.

Comment: Ah!!! Now I see.  I tried a typeof on the bill.setPlaceInLine(2) call and it does return "undefined", which is what the comparison is using.  Now I understand.  Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: Quick question - my "person" object is just an example I made up...I'm actually calling a function on a object from another library.  Is it a general standard to not have a return value on setters?  Or was the library built poorly and it should have a return value?

Comment: @user1607577 most libraries return the object you are operating on, so that you can do chained operations like `bill.placeInLine().changeName("billl")`

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing to the returnvalue of the function.

Unless you actually return a value via `return this.placeInLine;` it will compare to the `undefined` always resulting in `false`.

Change your code to this:

```
this.setPlaceInLine = function(place) {
    return this.placeInLine = place;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

setPlaceInLine returns nothing.  And nothing is evaluated as less than 1.
You could update setPlaceInLine to return the value:

```
function personObject() {
    this.name = 'First Name';
    this.placeInLine = 1;
    this.setPlaceInLine = function(place) {
        this.placeInLine = place;
        return place;
    }
}
```