# How to add in a method to a javascript class?

Tags: javascript

How could I put setPosition inside of the class `DrawClockHand`? Is `DrawCLockHand` even a class technically in Javascript.

Code:

```
var DrawClockHand = function(cv) {
    this._cv = cv;
    this._ctx = cv.getContext('2d');
    this.TIME = 1000;
    this._r = 50;
}

DrawClockHand.prototype.setPosition = function(x,y) {
    x = x || 0;
    y = y || 0;
    this._x = x;
    this._y = y;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean as a function on an instance of an object created by the constructor function `DrawClockHand` as opposed to on the prototype as you have above?

Comment: *DrawClockHand* is a function. If called with *new*, if behaves as a constructor. There are no classes in ECMAScript (but [*ES6*](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-class-definitions) would like to change that).

Comment: Yes, on reply one. If I want to make this into a class how would I go about doing that. ECMAScript is that another form of Javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Class.method vs. Class.prototype.method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635116/javascript-class-method-vs-class-prototype-method)

Answer (score 5):

DrawClockHand is not a class, it is just a function that creates an object with a given structure (if called with the new operator).

If you call the DrawClockHand function like this:

```
var o = new DrawClockHand(someVal);
```

Then you will be creating a new object with the structure established by the DrawClockHand function. In that case, in the *o* object will also have the setPosition method because it was set as a DrawClockHand's propotype property.

So this is valid

```
var o = new DrawClockHand(someVal);
o.setPosition(1,2);
```

Comment: is this a good way of doing it. Or should I have created a real class with real constructors in Javascript. I am somewhat new to the Javascript aspect of things.

Comment: First of all, when you code javascript stop thinking in classes. A class defines a static data structure (including methods), and javascript was designed to be a very dynamic language. Nevertheless there are lots of cases where you may want to define a concrete strcuture for a set of differents objects, in that cases you should use a creational pattern. One creational pattern is the exposed in my answer where you have a function that defines the strcture and creates the object with that given structure.

Comment: I strongly recomend you this readings:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/tag/ecma-262-3/

http://leoasis.github.io/posts/2013/01/24/javascript-object-creation-patterns/