# When emulating a 'class', why set the methods in the .prototype property and not in the constructor itself?

Tags: javascript, class, object, constructor, prototype

I'm trying to understand 'classes' in JavaScript.

Usually emulating classes in JavaScript looks something like this:

```
function MyClass(someParameter) {
    this.someValue = someParameter;
    this.someOtherValue = "green";
}

MyClass.prototype.someMethod = function() {
    console.log("Hello!");
};
```

While the non-function members are set inside the constructor, the method is added outside of the constructor, to the `.prototype` property of the constructor.

I'd like to understand why. Why not create the methods inside the constructor, just like the rest of the members? Meaning:

```
function MyClass(someParameter) {
    this.someValue = someParameter;
    this.someOtherValue = "green";

    this.someMethod = function() {
        console.log("Hello!");
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635116/javascript-class-method-vs-class-prototype-method

Comment: There's no such thing as a class in JavaScript. However there are some ways to create an object. (http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/)

Comment: Properties on the prototype are **shared** by all instances. Properties you assign to `this` in the constructor are distinct. You can set function-valued properties in the constructor, and you can set non-function-valued properties on the prototype.

Comment: @Pointy I see. So what I'm asking is, why would I choose to set the non-function properties inside the constructor using `.this`, but the function properties outside the constructor using `.prototype`?

Comment: @AvivCohn: Because *"properties on the prototype are **shared** by all instances."* Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript

Comment: The *why* part of the question largely depends on the needs of the software being written.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some main points:

- Performance: Ctor methods are created each time an instance is created while prototype methods are created once and inherited.prototype is better here.
- Ctor methods have access to privates inside your function while prototype ones don't.

Answer (score 1):

> Why not create the methods inside the constructor, just like the rest of the members?

Because methods are usually not distinct between instances. In your example every instance has *the same* `someMethod` method, doing the exact same thing. So it only makes sense to create that method only **once**.

Scalar data on the other hand is often *specific* to the instance (i.e. distinct between instances) and thus should be initialized in the constructor.

---

FWIW, ECMAScript6 introduces the new `class` syntax which encourages such structure.

```
function MyClass(someParameter) {
    this.someValue = someParameter;
    this.someOtherValue = "green";
}

MyClass.prototype.someMethod = function() {
    console.log("Hello!");
};
```

is equivalent to

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(someParameter) {
        this.someValue = someParameter;
        this.someOtherValue = "green";
    }

    someMethod() {
       console.log("Hello!");
    }
}
```