# Creating a Class Method

Tags: javascript

```
function Person(firstName = "John", lastName = 'Doe', age = 0, gender = 'Male') {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.sayFullName = function() {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName
    };
}

Person.prototype.greetExtraTerrestrials = function(raceName) {
    return `Welcome to Planet Earth ${raceName}`;
};
```

What is wrong with this code? Doesn't it create a class method called `greetExtraTerrestrials`?

Comment: What does not work? What is the error message? Without a problem statement, every code is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't place that function on prototype, place that on Class itself like

```
Person.greetExtraTerrestrials = function(raceName) { 
    return `Welcome to Planet Earth ${raceName}`;
};
```

and call it like

```
Person.greetExtraTerrestrials('ABC');
```

Comment: perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do **both**! The difference in

```
class Person(...) {
    ...
}

Person.myFunction = function(val) { // This is a public function
    return val;
}

Person.prototype.myFunction = function(val) { // This is a private function
    return val;
}
```

is how you **access** it.

Access the *public* function :

```
var r = Person.myFunction("Hello!");
console.log(r);
```

Access the *private* function:

```
var person1 = new Person(...);
var r = person1.myFunction("Hello!");
console.log(r);
```

See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635116/javascript-class-method-vs-class-prototype-method).

Answer (score 0):

Actually it works, but firstly you need to create an instance of Person to be able call its methods. For example:

```
var john = new Person("John");
console.log(john.greetExtraTerrestrials("predator"));
```