# Instantiating express

Tags: node.js, express

I have an issue where I need to load express like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

In order to get .static to work:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'views'));
```

Any reason why I can't use shorthand:

```
var app = require('express')();
```

When I try the short hand it says express.static is undefined and my script won't run.  Is this just a feature that's not supported by express?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any reason why I can't use shorthand:
>
> ***var app = require('express')();***

If you considered this statement from your script,

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'views'));
```

you are using `static` method of express.In order to use this method,you must import `express` first and store it in some variables like  u did

```
var express = require('express');
```

> From [express#express.js](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/express.js)
>
> ```
> exports.static = require('serve-static');
> ```
>
> `static` defined at class level.

then instantiate it 
like this

`var app = express();`

to get the access to object level(prototype) method and properties like 
`app#use` `app#engine` etc.

From [express#application](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/application.js) `//line no 78`

EDIT :

> but then why can't I use app.static if I did **var app = require('express')();**

As I said,`.static` is the class level method and not the instance/object(prototype) level.

So,by  `var app = require('express')()`
you will get express instance / object (prototype) which dont have **app.static** method.So,you can't use.

Read more [javascript-class-method-vs-class-prototype-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635116/javascript-class-method-vs-class-prototype-method)

Comment: It makes sense that require('express')  will allow express.static to work, but then why can't I use app.static if I did var app = require('express')();

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

This will work: `const app = (() => require('express'))()();`

But you still need `express` itself, so there literally is no real point to requiring twice.

Comment: Didn't know I could put double() after a require, are there any other functions that could be used for? Yes, still have to require('express') into it's own variable to get static.