# Reuse function between two webpack modules

Tags: javascript, function, webpack

I'm trying to reuse a function from existing webpack module instead recreating it again.

Example code from first module for view#1 looks like:

```
    SearchPopupView.prototype.highlightUser = function(item)
    {
        var self = this;

        self.selUser(item);
    }
```

then in the new module, for view#2 - the same HTML template as view#1, I try to reuse the same function:

```
 UserSearch = __webpack_require__(/*! View/Popup/UserSearch */ 17)

 SearchAccountPopupView.prototype.highlightAccount = function(item)
 {
    UserSearch.prototype.highlightUser(item);
 }
```

it will execute function from a first module but will throw an error that

> self.selUser is not a function

My question is can I reuse any function which operates on a view#1 elements or just those which are only computing values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would advice you to take a look into this: JavaScript: Class.method vs. Class.prototype.method

[JavaScript: Class.method vs. Class.prototype.method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635116/javascript-class-method-vs-class-prototype-method)

Second, is the UserSearch, you are obtaining, an object (was defined using the keyword new prior to obtain it)? If so, then you don't need to use the prototype. You can use

```
 UserSearch.highlightUser(item);
```

If it is not an object, then you need to instantiate it or you need to change your class to use static methods.

Comment: `UserSearch` is not an object. Sounds like I will need to use static methods. Can you provide some example on instantiation of declared function?

Comment: let userSearch = new UserSearch(); userSearch.highlightUser(item);

Comment: Remember that we are missing parts of your code so its harder to give you a pin-point  solution. Based on the code you are working on is that we can know how to refactor it to your purpose.

Comment: Yes, it makes a sense. At leas I know where to start. Thanks!